# What does @ mean?

Tags: phonology, historical-linguistics

What does “@“ sign mean in phonology or historical linguistics?

I saw “*@” in the context of restriction.

Comment: Please add an example of the context where you encountered that sign (with citation, if possible).

Comment: Thank you for commenting ! I only saw @ sign and no example.

Answer (score 5):

it's the X-SAMPA symbol for schwa. X-SAMPA was a system for representing the IPA using only ASCII. Now that unicode has become so ubiquitous it's largely obsolete, but you do still occasionally come across it

Comment: Thank you for answering! I understood.